# Registration Form - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

I am writing my first jQuery Mobile app (so I am sorry if it is a silly question) and I want to create a sign up form, in order to keep the users of the app.

In plain HTML i set up a local server with XAMPP for example, and this can be easily done, by using PHP to get data from the HTML form and then insert users into a database.

Now in a mobile app, using jQuery Mobile how can I implement this?I mean what should I use?PHP and a local server again?

I ask because I have searched a lot in the Web, but I can't find something especially for jQuery Mobile and I am confused.

Thank you all, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  You question is a bit unclear but if you are just trying to build a mobile web application you can use whatever web development stack you want, in much the same way that you are used to.  Here is a link to the jQuery Mobile [Getting started](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/) docs.

If you are trying to build a native mobile application with jQuery mobile you will need to pair JQM with a framework like [Phonegap / Apache Cordova](http://phonegap.com/about/).

Comment: Yes i need to pair JQM with PhoneGap.

Comment: In that case you need to configure Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the client and server.  JQM has a FAQ page you should read: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/how-configure-phonegap-cordova.html

Comment: Ok thanks for your consideration...I will mark your answer as accepted, but one last question... :)
I found that link: http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/
Can you please check that?
I assume that I want something like that, right?
Thanks again!

Comment: That looks like a good starting point.  You will still need to explicitly set cors in php with something like: <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>